# What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\binom{n}{k} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

It was originally asked on another website but nobody has been able to prove the numerical result. The attempts usually go by Stirling's approximation or try to use the Silverman-Toeplitz theorem.

Comment: I assume that's a binomial coefficient?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\binom nk=\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\left(\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\right)$$

$$=(n+1)\ln(n!)-2\sum_{k=0}^n\ln(k!)$$

$$=(n+1)\ln(n!)-2\ln(0!\times1!\times2!\times\dots\times n!)$$

Comment: Yes, that we agree on

Comment: Wow, could you provide the numerical result you have found?

Comment: 1/2, but I don't understand the wow component of your  comment

Comment: It is intrinsically difficult to evaluate.

Comment: Equivalent to trying to evaluate $(n+1)\int_0^n\psi^{(0)}(x)dx-2\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^k\psi^{(0)}(y)dy$, where $\psi^{(0)}(\mu)$ is the digamma function.  Some of it's properties might help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213843/what-is-the-limit-of-this-sequence-involving-logs-of-binomials?noredirect=1&lq=1. Also check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1306730/321264) answer.

Answer (score 6):

As already noted by @SimpleArt, the expression equals

$$\tag 1 (n+1)\ln n!-2\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k!.$$

The sum on the right equals

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k}\ln j = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(n—j+1)\ln j= (n+1)\ln n! - \sum_{j=1}^{n} j\ln j.$$

Therefore $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 -(n+1)\ln n! +2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} j\ln j.$$

Now $\ln n! = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k,$ and this sum can be compared nicely with $\int_1^n \ln x \, dx$ to get

$$\ln n! = n\ln n - n +O(\ln n).$$

Similarly, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j\ln j $ can be compared to $\int_1^\infty x \ln x \, dx$ to give

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} j\ln j = \frac{n^2\ln n}{2}-\frac{n^2}{4} +O(n\ln n).$$

Putting this altogether, we see some nice cancellation shows $(2)$ equals $n^2/2 + O(n\ln n).$ Dividing by $n^2$ then gives $1/2$ for the desired limit.

Comment: How can we compare a summation with a integral and is this possible in all cases?

Comment: We do this often, but no, not in all cases. Monotonicity is important. Are you familiar with the integral test for series?

Comment: very nice (+1) !

Comment: @navinstudent Integral test for monotone functions sets an upper and lower bound, allowing for asymptotic expansion to be easily made.

Answer (score 6):

By Stolz Cezaro
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\binom{n}{k}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{2n+1} \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\ln\binom{n+1}{k}-  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\binom{n}{k} \right)\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{2n+1} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left(\ln\binom{n+1}{k}- \ln\binom{n}{k} \right)\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{2n+1} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!} \frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!} \right)\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1-k)}  \right)}{2n+1}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1-k)}  \right)}{2n+1}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{(n+1)!}  \right)}{2n+1}\\
$$

Applying stolz Cezaro again, we get
$$
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}  \right)-\ln\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{(n+1)!}  \right)}{2} \\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}  \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^n}  \right)}{2} \\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(\frac{(n+2)^{n}}  {(n+1)^n}  \right)}{2}\\
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac { \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n}{2}\\
=\frac{\ln(e)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is as exact an answer as you want,
from my answer here:
[Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \big\{(1+\frac1{k})^{k+\frac1{2}}\big/e\big\} = \dfrac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427045/prove-that-prod-k-1-infty-big-1-frac1kk-frac12-big-e-big)

$$\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \sim
C^{-1}\frac{e^{n(n+2)/2}}{n^{(3n+2)/6}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/4}}
\exp\big\{-\sum_{p\ge 1}\frac{B_{p+1}+B_{p+2}}{p(p+1)}\frac1{n^p}\big\}\text{ as }n \to \infty
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
C
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac1{n^{1/12}}
\prod_{k=1}^n \big\{k!\big/\sqrt{2\pi k}\big(\frac{k}{e}\big)^k\big\}\\
&\approx 1.04633506677...\\
\end{align}
$$
and the $\{B_p\}$
are the Bernoulli numbers,
defined by
$$\sum_{p \ge 0} B_p\frac{x^p}{p!} = \frac{x}{e^x-1}
.$$

Taking logs,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \ln\binom{n}{k} \sim
\ln C+n(n+2)/2-(3n+2)\ln n/6-(2n+1)\ln(2\pi)/4
-\sum_{p\ge 1}\frac{B_{p+1}+B_{p+2}}{p(p+1)}\frac1{n^p}\\
\text{ as }n \to \infty
$$

Dividing by $n^2$,

$$\dfrac1{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n \ln\binom{n}{k} 
\to \dfrac12
\text{ as }n \to \infty
$$